# Cannot tunnel a service in cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I get the following error on my Cloud Foundry installation when I try to tunnel a mongodb service.

```
vmc tunnel mongodb-1234
Deploying tunnel application 'caldecott'.
Create a password: *******
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (1K): OK   
Push Status: OK
Binding Service [mongodb-1234]: OK
Staging Application: OK                                                         
Starting Application: OK                                                        
**Error: Cannot determine URL for caldecott-8e54b.vcap.me**
```

In the other hand, the tunneling works fine when I target the
`api.cloudfondry.org`, so it seems that my installation isn't
properly configured. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was on my hosts file. I had to add an entry like this: 
{IP Address} {Caldecott URL}

Comment: However, the client cannot start Starting tunnel to mongodb-tmaas on port 10000.
1: none
2: mongo
Which client would you like to start?: 2
Launching 'mongo --host localhost --port 10000 -u ...'

MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
connecting to: localhost:10000/db
Fri Jun 08 16:52:18 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Fri Jun 08 16:52:18 Error: Error during mongo startup. :: caused by :: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: localhost:10000 query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } shell/mongo.js:86
exception: connect failed
Error: 'mongo' executation failed; is it in your $PATH?

Comment: The good thing is that the problem persist with MySQL too.
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
Error: 'mysql' executation failed; is it in your $PATH?

Comment: Do you must have use vmc for using mongodb on cloudfoundry?

Answer (score 0):

For questions related to installations of the Cloud Foundry opensource project, the best resource is the vcap-dev Google Group: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/vcap-dev/

At first glance, it appears to be a URL mapping issue. Perhaps you didn't set up the SSH tunnel to port 80 or 443 of the VACP host?